# For few users, Sqlite DB returns error code 9(interupted)

Tags: sqlite

During the application run sqlite is throwing an error with code 9(Interupted) for few users for any query. This is seen sporadically.

I have tried running the same query separately in sqlite console and the query is working fine. 
Need some help with this. I am new to SQLite DB.

The query is simple . please find a simple query below

SELECT "item1", "item2", "item3" FROM TABLE1 WHERE (item2 = '123456789')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your answer to include more details, including the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Hi jkdev i have added the query. its a simple query. only in few pcs the issues are happening.